# Erkenbrand of Westfold

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings, tolkiens-legendarium, adaptation-comparison

Is it ever stated why Erkenbrand of Westfold isn't in the movies? He plays such a vital part in the book of the Two Towers with Gandalf aiding the battle of Helms Deep it just seems strange to leave him out?

Comment: Excellent question - where IS Erkenbrand of... wait, who?

Answer (score 7):

According to the [Tolkien Gateway](http://tolkiengateway.net/wiki/Erkenbrand),

> In both The Lord of the Rings (1978 film) and The Lord of the Rings: The Two Towers, Erkenbrand's position is taken by Éomer. This is mainly because he [that is, Erkenbrand] would appear unintroduced, and the return of Éomer serves the films' climax better. Erkenbrand did appear on a Decipher Card. Weta's Mike Grealish served as the character, wearing the armour of Théodred, which did not get much attention in the film.

So it sounds like his role in the book was considered to be better filled by Éomer, in both portrayals.  This happens all the time in film adaptations, and personally I think Éomer served this function very well.  I had actually forgotten about Erkenbrand entirely, and I've read the books several times...

For those who are interested, here's the card mentioned in that quote:

[image]

Comment: Plenty of other characters received the same treatment, including Gildor and Glorfindel.